# Old UIView controller class over-written by new one

Tags: ios, xcode

Hello I'm new to iOS development, I did a blunder mistake. My project contained a UIViewController class called 'BXViewController' and by mistake I made a new class also named 'BXViewController' Xcode did warn me about naming conflicts.
Now the old class is over written by new one, and needless to say all code contained in old view controller class is gone. 
Is there a way to recover the loss? Undoing does not work.

Comment: If the original file is replaced, there is no way to bring it back..
Check the folder where the file is..

Comment: Were you using version control (for example `git`)? If so, then perhaps your original `BXViewController` is still available in the commit history.

Comment: Thanks, for replies. Lesson learned the hard way. I'll be using version control from now on.